# Multiple join on same column with where clause in mysql does not work

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - vehicles and employees.

Vehicle has two fields -1) owner (refers to id of employees) 2) assigned_to : (refers to id of employees).

I want to create a report with owner and assigned to names. The following query works when I remove the where clause, but with where clause it gives error as

> Unknown column O.firstname in where clause.

```
SELECT V.*, CONCAT(O.firstname,' ',O.lastname) AS ownerName, 
CONCAT(A.firstname,' ',A.lastname) AS assigneeName 
FROM vehicles AS V LEFT JOIN employees AS O ON V.owner=O.id 
LEFT JOIN employees AS A ON V.assigned_to=A.id 
WHERE (`O.firstname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `O.lastname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `A.firstname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `A.lastname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `V.license_state` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `V.make` LIKE '%xyz%' OR `V.model` LIKE '%xyz%' )
```

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WHERE clause the column name with table alias name as

```
`O.firstname`
```

this is the wrong way, you can apply the backtick for the column name, not with the table alias name, it should be

```
O.`firstname`
```

Also if you are apply the `LEFT JOIN` related conditions in the `LEFT JOIN` itself, instead of the `WHERE` clause, it will not fail if the there is no entry in the `employees` tables:

So the query will be:

```
SELECT V.*, 
       CONCAT(O.firstname, ' ', O.lastname) AS ownerName, 
       CONCAT(A.firstname, ' ', A.lastname) AS assigneeName 
FROM vehicles AS V  
LEFT JOIN employees AS O ON V.owner = O.id AND (A.`firstname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR A.`lastname` LIKE '%xyz%')
LEFT JOIN employees AS A ON V.assigned_to = A.id AND (V.`license_state` LIKE '%xyz%' OR V.`make` LIKE '%xyz%' OR V.`model` LIKE '%xyz%')
WHERE O.`firstname` LIKE '%xyz%' OR O.`lastname` LIKE '%xyz%'
```

Comment: It was backtick causing issue. Great catch!